# Are the fractional parts of powers of $\pi$ divergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let us define $a_n$ as the fractional part of $\pi^n$.

In other words, define $a_n=\pi^n-\lfloor \pi^n \rfloor$.

Then, does the following limit exist? $$\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n$$Intuitively, it appears that it does not exist, though it does have a lower bound of $0$ and an upper bound of $1$. However, I have no idea how to proceed with a proof. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are right, the limit does not exist (verified with CAS), proving it on the other hand...

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD How did you verify that the limit doesn't exist with CAS?

Comment: In my opinion it has bonds but no value. Taking 1.2, it gives $0.2,0.44,0.728,0.0736$.. no continuity

Comment: @MiloBrandt I made a short program to approximate  the $\sup |a_n-a_m|$ for large $n,m>N$. The sequence doesn't seem to be Cauchy. This is not a proof, of course.

Comment: Notice if you take the logarithm it becomes a bit easier to understand. Then you're analyzing $n\log\pi-\sum_{k=1}^\infty{\frac{\lfloor \pi^n\rfloor^k}{k\pi^{kn}}}$.

Comment: There is no way for a non-monotonic sequence of irrational numbers in [0,1] to converge to a rational limit.

Comment: @frogfanitw where'd you get that idea? How about something like $a_n=1/2+(-1)^n*(\pi/(100n))$. It is a non-monotonic sequence of irrational number which converges to $1/2$

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83271/fractional-powers

Comment: "There is no way for a non-monotonic sequence of irrational numbers in [0,1] to converge to a rational limit."  Um... $x_n = 1/2 + (-1)^n*\pi^{-n}$.

Comment: I guess Occam's razor applies, I obviously over-generalized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The sequence $\{a_n\}$ does not converge.**

Furthermore, this sequence is said to be [equidistributed or uniformly distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_sequence), which means that 
the proportion of terms falling in any subinterval of $[0,1]$ is proportional to the length of the subinterval.

This is actually a specific case, of the more general question:

> If $a_n=x^n-\lfloor x^n \rfloor$, for what values of $x$ is the sequence $\{a_n\}$ equidistributed?

[Hardy](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.acta/1485887375) showed that the this sequence is equisitributed for almost all values of $x$. The set of numbers such that it is **not** equidstributed, has Lebesgue measure of zero, and are called [Pisot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisot%E2%80%93Vijayaraghavan_number) numbers. It  includes $\phi =\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $1+\sqrt{2}$.

Further details, visualizations and links can be found at the Wolfram [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EquidistributedSequence.html) site.

**Note**

For those who may be new to studying sequences that involve fractional parts, be aware that curly braces $\{ \cdot \}$ are (unfortunately) used to convey two different concepts:

- to define a sequence $\{a_n\} = \{a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots\}$;
- to define a function, where $\{x\} = x - \lfloor x \rfloor $, the fractional part of $x$.

Which usage is implied, can nearly always be deduced from context.