# Evaluate $\lim_{n\to \infty} \{(3+2\sqrt 2)^n\}$ where $\{x\}$ is the fractional part of $x$.

Tags: limits, number-theory

Evaluate: $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \{(3+2\sqrt 2)^n\}$$ where $\{x\}=x-[x]$

My Solution: Fractional part of  $\{(3+2\sqrt 2)^n\}$ will always be less than $1$ and greater than $0$. so as $n$ tends to infinity the value of limit would be closer to 1. But how to prove it theoretically? please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you think it would get closer to $1$? If $n$ increases, this doesn't cause the fractional part of an expression to increase. Try plugging in a few numbers for $n$, for example.

Comment: "would be closer to $1$" -- why?

Comment: Where did you encounter this limit? Were you studying linear difference equations? Giving [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) can help us help you better.

Comment: The Pisot-Vijayaraghavan numbers  are [defined here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisot%E2%80%93Vijayaraghavan_number) and they display similar kind of behaviour to that you expect from $3+2 \sqrt 2$, check the diophantine approximation section. You can prove that your number is a PV number from definition.

Comment: In fact, the answer to your question is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83271/fractional-powers?noredirect=1) where you will also find a lot of other useful links as well.

Comment: @Teresa by seeing your reference it's clear the limit as $n \to \infty $ is becoming 1.

Comment: Please avoid questions with math-only titles. They are discouraged for technical reasons - see [Guidelines for good use of MathJax on question titles](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730).

Comment: @Chris Indeed, this is the case.

Comment: Once you've gotten an answer for this, you might try showing that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left\{\frac{\left(3+2\sqrt2\right)^n}{4\sqrt2}\right\}=0$. This relates to Teresa Lisbon's [citation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisot%E2%80%93Vijayaraghavan_number) and makes $3+2\sqrt2$ a PV number.

Comment: Now that I read the citation closer, $\left\|\alpha^n\right\|=\frac12-\left|\left\{\alpha^n\right\}-\frac12\right|$ and so the fact that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left\{\left(3+2\sqrt2\right)^n\right\}=1$ shows that $3+2\sqrt2$ is a PV number.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** Investigate the expression  $$(3+2\sqrt2)^n+(3-2\sqrt 2)^n.$$

Answer (score 2):

$\{(3+2\sqrt 2\ )^n\}\\ \text{for n=1, }\{(3+2\sqrt 2 )\}=(3+2\sqrt 2)-[3+2\sqrt 2] =3+2\sqrt 2-[3+2\sqrt 2]\\ =2\sqrt2-[2\sqrt2]\approx 0.829\\ \text{now for } \ \ n=2, \{(3+2\sqrt 2)^2 \} =12\sqrt3 -[12\sqrt2] \approx 0.97 \\ \text{for} \ \ n=3, \ \{ (3+2\sqrt 2\ )^3\}=70\sqrt2-[70\sqrt2] \approx 0.99 \\ \text {Hence we can say}\ \ \\ \lim _{n \to \infty \{(3+2\sqrt 2\ )^n\}}=1$

Comment: Look at the way I thought previously and hence I drew an result to 1. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You may want to use text outside MathJax to lessen the rendering time.

Comment: The fact that the first three terms appear to be tending to $1$ does not prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left\{\left(3+2\sqrt2\right)^n\right\}=1$. This might better be added to your question as context for why you thought the limit should be $1$.

Comment: @Chris: If you don't want to, would you mind if I moved this answer into your question for context? The question is quite intriguing and can lead to some interesting number theory, and the added context might help prevent the question's possible closure and deletion.